# Filtering out Azure ServiceBus logs from WebJob Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, log-level

I have been trying to filter out information messages that my ServiceBus triggered webjob is sending in the Application Insights. These messages consist of these two logs:

> ReceiveBatchAsync start. MessageCount = 1 
> ReceiveBatchAsync done. Received '0' messages. LockTokens =

My goal is to only log information traces that I am logging in my code and ignore the logs coming from Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. How can I achieve this?

---

So far I have tried to add a filter using the following code in my program.cs file

```
b.AddFilter("Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus", LogLevel.Warning);
```

and I have also tried to add the following settings in my appsettings.json file

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning"
    }
},
```

---

As for my set up I am using the following packages which are of concern:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

The following code is my Logging configuration in the program.cs file.
[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Were you ever able to solve it?

Comment: I was not able to solve it so far. I believe there is a workaround by implementing Serilog (I have not tested if Serilog works), but I wish to solve it without including other third-party packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue to filter some Service Bus or EFCore logs.
I was able to partially solve this adding some hardcoded filter into the logging configuration code :

```cs
builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) => {

  // If the key exists in settings, use it to enable Application Insights.
  string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["EASY_APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
  
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey)) {
    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
  }

  b.AddConsole();
  b.AddFilter("Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus", LogLevel.Error);
  b.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Error);

});
```

But i would like to know how can i setup logging just in updating  settings from AppService's settings.

Comment: I tried to add setting into appsettings.json, into AppService Setting like 
{
    "name": "Logging:LogLevel:Default",
    "value": "Warning",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
but this does not work at all !